# how to merge two dataframes using if condition

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe_1: df3

| EventID | Postcode | Event_Start_Date | Event_End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 112223 | 2015-09-17 | 2015-09-30 |
| 234 | 112233 | 2015-09-30 | 2015-10-07 |
| 234 | 112323 | 2015-09-25 | 2015-10-05 |
| 456 | 331212 | 2001-06-17 | 2001-06-18 |
| 456 | 332211 | 2001-06-12 | 2001-06-12 |
| 456 | 332212 | 2001-06-14 | 2001-06-15 |
| 789 | 223321 | 1990-08-16 | 1990-08-16 |
| 789 | 223322 | 1990-08-12 | 1990-08-14 |
| 789 | 223324 | 1990-08-22 | 1990-08-22 |

Dateframe_2: df_NA

| ClaimNumber | Postcode | ReportDate | EventID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WC8285054 | 112233 | 2015-09-24 | NaN |
| WC6982237 | 112323 | 2015-09-27 | NaN |
| WC6982242 | 112323 | 2015-09-08 | NaN |
| WC6982243 | 112323 | 2015-09-07 | NaN |
| WC6982248 | 223324 | 1990-08-1 | NaN |

if in a postcode in Dateframe_2 is equal to postcode in Dataframe_1

```
and  ReportDate in Dataframe_2 lies between Event_Start_Date and Event_End_Date than 

    than EventID in Dataframe_2 is same as EventID in Dateframe_1.
```

my code is giving valueserrors:

```
for ClaimNumber, Postcode, ReportDate, EventID, *_ in df_NA:

    for EventID, Postcode, Event_Start_Date, Event_End_Date, *_ in df3:

        if df_NA['Postcode']==df3['Postcode'] and df_NA['ReportDate']>= df3['Event_Start_Date'] and df_NA['ReportDate']<= df3['Event_End_Date']:

            df_NA['EventID']=df['EventID']
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e7f9a0046929> in <module>
      1 for Postcode, ReportDate, EventID, *_ in df_NA:
      2     for EventID, Postcode, Event_Start_Date, Event_End_Date, *_ in df3:
----> 3         if df_NA['Postcode']==df3['Postcode'] and df_NA['ReportDate']>= df3['Event_Start_Date'] and df_NA['ReportDate']<= df3['Event_End_Date']:
      4             df_NA['EventID']=df['EventID']
      5 

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     63         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     64 
---> 65         return method(self, other)
     66 
     67     return new_method

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __eq__(self, other)
     27     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     28     def __eq__(self, other):
---> 29         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)
     30 
     31     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ne__")

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   4971 
   4972         if isinstance(other, Series) and not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 4973             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
   4974 
   4975         lvalues = extract_array(self, extract_numpy=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Comment: You should probably be doing some kind of [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) operation instead of iterating over both DataFrames.

Comment: But i am unable to find solution for merge with if-else condition.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if in a postcode in Dateframe_2 is equal to postcode in Dataframe_1

and  ReportDate in Dataframe_2 lies between Event_Start_Date and Event_End_Date than 

    than EventID in Dataframe_2 is same as EventID in Dateframe_1.